# MediaMuxer: No sync frames for video track

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, video-encoding, buffering, mediamuxer

I have been trying to modify bigflake's DecodeEditEncode to edit an mp4 file and then encode it back to mp4. I have looked around the internet and couldn't find a solution. I am setting the IFRAME interval and FPS, yet the Muxer still complains about sync frames and is unable to stop.

Could anyone with more experience point out what am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot in advance :)

```
    private static void encodeToMp4(MediaCodec decoder,
                                OutputSurface outputSurface, InputSurface inputSurface, MediaCodec encoder) {
    final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 10000;
    ByteBuffer[] decoderInputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    MediaMuxer mediaMuxer = null;

    int inputChunk = 0;
    int outputCount = 0;
    boolean outputDone = false;
    boolean inputDone = false;
    boolean decoderDone = false;
    while (!outputDone) {
        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "edit loop");
        // Feed more data to the decoder.
        if (!inputDone) {
            int inputBufIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
            if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer buffer = decoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
                int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
                if (sampleSize < 0) {
                    inputChunk++;
                    // End of stream -- send empty frame with EOS flag set.
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 0, 0L,
                            MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                    inputDone = true;
                } else {
                    // Copy a chunk of input to the decoder.  The first chunk should have
                    // the BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG flag set.
                    buffer.clear();
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, sampleSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                    extractor.advance();

                    inputChunk++;
                }
            }
        }
        // Assume output is available.  Loop until both assumptions are false.
        boolean decoderOutputAvailable = !decoderDone;
        boolean encoderOutputAvailable = true;
        try {
            mediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile.getAbsolutePath(), MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MediaFormat mediaFormat = extractor.getTrackFormat(0);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 20);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 10);
        int trackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(mediaFormat);
        mediaMuxer.start();
        while (decoderOutputAvailable || encoderOutputAvailable) {
            int encoderStatus = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
            if (encoderStatus == (int) MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                // no output available yet
                encoderOutputAvailable = false;
            } else if (encoderStatus == (int) MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
            } else if (encoderStatus == (int) MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                MediaFormat newFormat = encoder.getOutputFormat();
            } else { // encoderStatus >= 0
                ByteBuffer encodedData = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
                if (encodedData == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                }
                // Write the data to the output "file".
                if (info.size != 0) {
                    encodedData.position(info.offset);
                    encodedData.limit(info.offset + info.size);
                    byte[] data = new byte[encodedData.remaining()];
                    encodedData.get(data);
                    mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(trackIndex, encodedData, info);
                    // outputData.addChunk(encodedData, (int)info.Flags, info.PresentationTimeUs);
                    outputCount++;
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "encoder output " + info.size + " bytes");
                }
                outputDone = (info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0;
                encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
            }
            if (encoderStatus != (int) MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                // Continue attempts to drain output.
                continue;
            }
            // Encoder is drained, check to see if we've got a new frame of output from
            // the decoder.  (The output is going to a Surface, rather than a ByteBuffer,
            // but we still get information through BufferInfo.)
            if (!decoderDone) {
                int decoderStatus = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
                if (decoderStatus == (int) MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                    // no output available yet
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "no output from decoder available");
                    decoderOutputAvailable = false;
                } else if (decoderStatus == (int) MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                    //decoderOutputBuffers = decoder.GetOutputBuffers();
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "decoder output buffers changed (we don't care)");
                } else if (decoderStatus == (int) MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                    // expected before first buffer of data
                    MediaFormat newFormat = decoder.getOutputFormat();
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "decoder output format changed: " + newFormat);
                } else if (decoderStatus < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unexpected result from decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + decoderStatus);
                } else { // decoderStatus >= 0
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "surface decoder given buffer "
                            + decoderStatus + " (size=" + info.size + ")");
                    // The ByteBuffers are null references, but we still get a nonzero
                    // size for the decoded data.
                    boolean doRender = (info.size != 0);
                    // As soon as we call releaseOutputBuffer, the buffer will be forwarded
                    // to SurfaceTexture to convert to a texture.  The API doesn't
                    // guarantee that the texture will be available before the call
                    // returns, so we need to wait for the onFrameAvailable callback to
                    // fire.  If we don't wait, we risk rendering from the previous frame.
                    decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, doRender);
                    if (doRender) {
                        // This waits for the image and renders it after it arrives.
                        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "awaiting frame");
                        outputSurface.awaitNewImage();
                        outputSurface.drawImage();
                        // Send it to the encoder.
                        inputSurface.setPresentationTime(info.presentationTimeUs * 1000);
                        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "swapBuffers");
                        inputSurface.swapBuffers();
                    }
                    if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                        // forward decoder EOS to encoder
                        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "signaling input EOS");
                        if (WORK_AROUND_BUGS) {
                            // Bail early, possibly dropping a frame.
                            return;
                        } else {
                            encoder.signalEndOfInputStream();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (inputChunk != outputCount) {
        throw new RuntimeException("frame lost: " + inputChunk + " in, " +
                outputCount + " out");
    }
    mediaMuxer.stop();
    mediaMuxer.release();
    listener.onFinished();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed  all issues by using the following bigflake test instead[ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java). For everyone that is trying to achieve something similar, this sample is life saver. :)

Comment: Hey! in case you have been using ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest to edit frames. Could you tell me more how do you achieve this editing? I mean other than edit it using openGL magic? Are you able to get bytes for every frame and update them somehow?